# What's the owner of SqlServerAgent job for?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, maintenance, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plans

What is the possible use of owner of an SQL Server Agent job, I wonder?

Removed, and left it blank and the job still succeeds

[image: SqlServer Agent Job Owner]

Comment: Fulproof - you should unaccept my answer, and accept the answer provided by @GreenstoneWalker since it is a much more complete and useful answer than mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(edit:  Although this answer was accepted, and is valid, please ensure you read the [other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53506/10832) by [@Greenstone-Walker](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/21137/greenstone-walker) since it has excellent information)

As [Billinkc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2131/billinkc) noted, a job can be edited only by its owner or members of the sysadmin role.  And as [Shawn Melton](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/507/shawn-melton) noted, removing the owner from the job simply ensures your login will become the owner.  You can see this by looking at a system stored procedure in the msdb database:  `exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name = 'somejob';`

Books Online has an article about SQL Server Agent Job Security entitled "[Give Others Ownership of a Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178031.aspx)" which describes the process well.

Answer (score 22):

The job owner determines the execution context of the job's steps.

For a T-SQL job step: If the job owner is a sysadmin then the step will execute as either the SQL Server Agent service account or a specified database user (set on the Advanced page of the Job Step Properties dialog). If the job owner is not a sysadmin then the step will execute as the job owner.

For other job steps: If the job owner is a sysadmin then the step will execute as either the SQL Server Agent service account or a specified Proxy. If the job owner is not a sysadmin then the step will execute as a specified Proxy (which requires the job owner to have permission to use the proxy).

A SQL Agent Proxy is created based on a SQL Server Credential which stores the secret associated with some external security principal. For example, sysadmin Kim creates a Credential for ADVENTUREWORKS\Bob and then creates a Proxy based on that Credential. She makes the Proxy active for the CmdExec subsystem. She gives (nonsysadmin) Qin the rights to use that Proxy. Qin can now create a CmdExec job step that executes as ADVERNTUREWORKS\Bob.

See [Implement SQL Server Agent Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190926%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) in Books Online.