# Strange wait types after enabling CDC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We recently enabled CDC on four tables in a busy database and since then we are capturing a lot of sessions that are waiting on XE_BUFFERMGR_FREEBUF_EVENT. When we see this wait type CDC is trying to INSERT into the associated CT table, and the wait duration can be up to 10ms.

I've stopped all XE sessions on the instance but I still see the same issue and this could be causing some issues on the wider system

Has anyone else seen this?

We're running SQL Server 2012 SP4.

Comment: According to [sqlskills](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/xe_buffermgr_freebuf_event/) it could have two different causes and the XE was one of them. Since you eliminated that one, you should verify the other: *Audits experience a delay. This can indicate a disk bottleneck on the drive where the audits are written*. Can you verify the disk performance?

Comment: Ok it does seem like the issue could be Audit related. There is an audit configured for this DB that pretty much audits every table so I guess CDC was competing for resources around that. I'll have to look at excluding the server login that CDC uses to avoid this.

Comment: Aren't you gonna break CDC by doing that? If that's gonna be your approach, wouldn't it be better to disable CDC instead? Also, I recommend you verify if there's a disk bottleneck at the moment (and maybe you can fix it and keep the Audits and CDC working together if you need them both).

Comment: We have the same Audit on another DB that uses CDC heavily and we haven't experienced the same issue. I believe this is because the DB audit is monitoring a lot less compared to the other, busier DB. If I can get an exclusion agreed for the account that the CDC capture job runs as I believe it'll be ok. That account is disabled by default (SA) and only used in certain scenarios. Unless there is a way to change the user that the CDC capture job runs as?

Comment: Yes, check [What's the owner of SqlServerAgent job for?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53362/whats-the-owner-of-sqlserveragent-job-for). But I believe you might be barking up the wrong tree. Notice the note at the end of the [Change Data Capture Agent Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#change-data-capture-agent-jobs) section.

Comment: Also, see the [Capture Job Customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/administer-and-monitor-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#capture-job-customization) doc. Since one cause for your problem might be disk related as I mentioned before, I recommend you read this [Monitoring Read/Write Latency](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/03/io-subsystem/monitoring-read-write-latency) post. Are the values on your environment good or bad according to that scale?